# gnuplot histogram : negative values go down instead go up

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I try to generate a histogram plot with gnuplot. I have positive and negative values. Positive values go to the top of the chart, but negative values go to the bottom of the chart..
I would like to change the base for go up and go down [image: values go down]
from 0 to -100 for example.

Maybe, it's not the good type of graphic to do that ?

I have tried this :

> gnuplot -e "set terminal png size 20000, 1500; set yrange [-100:*]; set title 'VU meter 0'; set style data histogram; set style histogram clustered gap 1; set style fill solid 1 noborder; plot 'testVUmeter0.tsv' using 2:xticlabels(1)" > out.png

Thanks

Comment: I dont quite understand. If you have 2 y values, say 5 and -5, the first histogram will go from y=0 to y=5, and the second will go from y=0 to y=-5. What would you prefer to see?

Comment: @meuh For example, I have two values 3 and -2. I want to see my 2 values that start from -5 for example. Currently, the base is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the plotting styles `histogram` and `with boxes` always start at y=0.
Assuming I understood your question correctly, you want to shift this zero level e.g. to -100.
As long as you do not need an advanced histogram style but just simple boxes, one possible solution could be to use the plotting style `with boxxyerror`. Compared to @meuh's solution, here, gnuplot automatically takes care about the y-tics.

**Code:**

```
### shift zero for boxes
reset session

$Data <<EOD
A   -20
B  -140
C   100
D  -340
E  +250 
F     0
EOD

myOffset = -100
myWidth = 0.8
set style fill solid 1.0

set arrow 1 from graph 0, first myOffset to graph 1, first myOffset nohead ls -1
set style textbox opaque

plot $Data u 0:2:($0-myWidth/2.):($0+myWidth/2.):(myOffset):2:xtic(1) w boxxyerror notitle, \
     '' u 0:2:2 w labels boxed notitle 
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate a new y value at each point, taking into account some wanted offset.  For example, setting `bot=-20` to give a bottom y value of -20 you can refer to `($2-bot)` to convert, say, -5 to `-5-(-20)=`15` above 0.

```
set terminal png size 400,300
set output "out.png"
set style data histogram
set style histogram clustered gap 1
set style fill solid 1 noborder
bot=-20
set yrange [0:*]
set ytics  ("-10" -10-bot, "0" 0-bot, "10" 10-bot, "20" 20-bot, "30" 30-bot)
plot "data" using (($2)-bot):xticlabels(1) notitle,  \
     ""  using 0:($2+3-bot):(sprintf("%d",$2)) with labels notitle
```

with data of

```
1 33
2 44
3 22
4 -12
```

gives the plot:

[image]